# Javascript / Jquery variable scope issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently having an 'interesting' issue where my functions and variables are being dropped out of scope / erroring as undefined under some peculiar circumstances. Particularly with the `CheckComplete` function.

The following code works completely fine without any errors:

```
// JavaScript Document
"use strict"

$(document).ready(function() {

    var buttonsClicked = new Array();

    $(".screen .button-container > div").each(function(){
        buttonsClicked.push(false);
    });
    $(".screen .button-container > div").click(function(){
        $(".screen .information-container > div").toggleClass("hidden",true);
        $(".screen .information-container > div:eq("+$(this).index()+")").toggleClass("hidden",false);
        buttonsClicked[$(this).index()] = true;
        CheckComplete();
    });

    function CheckComplete()
    {
        var complete = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < buttonsClicked.length; i++)
        {
            if(!buttonsClicked[i])
            {
                complete = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(complete)
        {
            Navigation.SetNextScreen("menu");
        }
    }
});
```

However the strangest issue arises when I place the `CheckComplete` function **outside** of the `$(document).ready(){})` declaration. like so:

```
   // JavaScript Document
"use strict"

var buttonsClicked;

$(document).ready(function() {

    buttonsClicked = new Array();

    $(".screen .button-container > div").each(function(){
        buttonsClicked.push(false);
    });
    $(".screen .button-container > div").click(function(){
        $(".screen .information-container > div").toggleClass("hidden",true);
        $(".screen .information-container > div:eq("+$(this).index()+")").toggleClass("hidden",false);
        buttonsClicked[$(this).index()] = true;
        CheckComplete();
    });
}); 


function CheckComplete()
    {
        var complete = true;
        for(var i = 0; i < buttonsClicked.length; i++)
        {
            if(!buttonsClicked[i])
            {
                complete = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(complete)
        {
            Navigation.SetNextScreen("menu");
        }
    }
```

The **first time** I load the page this works completely fine. However when i press F5 or refresh the page via the button. I receive the following error when `CheckComplete()` is called: `ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable buttonsClicked`. Hereafter the no matter how many times the page is refreshed, it continues to error. This can only be solved when I close the tab/window and revisit the page.

This script is loaded dynamically at run time, however I struggle to see how this would be affecting the functionality, when everything else in the script is working and I have completely disabled cache. Compounding my confusion this only occurs in Firefox...?

It would be nice if someone could please shed some light on why this is the case, as defining all of my functions inside `$(document).ready(){}` doesn't appease my perfectionism and I wouldn't consider it syntactically correct either.

### Update

@SandeepNayak was correct, the "use strict" statement was the culprit... I am perplexed as to why this would cause such an issue in Firefox and no other though ??????

Comment: remove this  buttonsClicked = new Array(); from document.ready and declare var buttonsClicked = new Array();

Comment: Have you tried a different name for the variable? Its odd that it throws in CheckComplete as you do not assign anything to it in that function. Are you sure that the error is in that function?

Comment: You say the script is loaded dynamically, so what I suspect is that the variable is not global as the script may be wrapped inside a function. If you try declaring and accessing the variable vial bracket notation `window["buttonsClicked"] = []; // to create` and `window["buttonsClicked"].push(foo); // to access` that should indicate that the scope is not global (if it works as bracket notation) and that the error is in the function `SetNextScreen` as I suspect you are attempting to access it there.

Comment: It is happening because of the `use strict`. I have come across situations when globals are not implicitly recognised when `use strict` is used

Comment: @user2181397 assigning of the variable could be anywhere in the whole script, i'm not sure that this would be the issue.

Comment: can you please create a jsfiddle

Comment: @Blindman67 I have just tried renaming a whole bunch of things to no avail. You were correct though the error was coming from  `buttonsClicked = new Array();` just inside the `$(document).ready(){}` function. I will add this revelation to the question in a minute. Further thoughts?

Comment: Wow @SandeepNayak you were correct! it is happening because of the `use strict` statement.

Comment: @Zze: Right, but not sure why that is happening in your case since you have explicitly declared `buttonsClicked` at the global level!

Comment: Its just a thing to try, maybe nothing but convert `$(this).index()` to a number just to make sure you are not trying to referance a property. thought that should not throw the error you get.  Try `buttonsClicked[Number($(this).index())]` and see what happens.

Comment: @SandeepNayak I updated my question. Also very confused..

Comment: Yes Use strict is the reason but the code you have shown us, it should not be happening. DONT stop using use strict or you will end up in a world of bugs.

Comment: @Blindman67 I completely agree. I have no intention of dropping the use strict so will continue investigating.

Comment: @Zze: Try using `window.propertyName` for the globals which you are facing the problem. That should solve the problem. For example use `window.buttonsClicked`..etc

Comment: @SandeepNayak Did you want to post an answer to this? Because both of your options (use strict and binding the vars to the window) were correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping the entire script in an anonymous function resolved this issue.

This may somehow be related to the warning: **"Use the function form of “use strict”** - still investigating the root cause, but at least those whom have the same issue can implement the following in the mean time.

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var buttonsClicked;

    $(document).ready(function() {

      buttonsClicked = new Array();

      $(".screen .button-container > div").each(function() {
        buttonsClicked.push(false);
      });
      $(".screen .button-container > div").click(function() {
        $(".screen .information-container > div").toggleClass("hidden", true);
        $(".screen .information-container > div:eq(" + $(this).index() + ")").toggleClass("hidden", false);
        buttonsClicked[$(this).index()] = true;
        CheckComplete();
      });
    });


    function CheckComplete() {
      var complete = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < buttonsClicked.length; i++) {
        if (!buttonsClicked[i]) {
          complete = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (complete) {
        Navigation.SetNextScreen("menu");
      }
 })();
```

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, Id lose the global var `buttonsClicked` altogether and do it with data attributes like this:

```js
  // JavaScript Document
  "use strict"

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $btns=$(".screen .button-container > div");
    $btns.click(function() {
      var $this =$(this);
      var cur=$btns.index($this);
      var $containers=$(".screen .information-container > div");
      $containers.removeClass("hidden").eq(cur).addClass("hidden");
      $this.attr('data-clicked','true'); // set btn to "clicked"
      CheckComplete();
    });
  });
  
  function CheckComplete() {
    var btns=$(".screen .button-container > div").length; // count btns
    var clickedBtns=$('[data-clicked="true"]').length; // count clicked btns
    if (btns==clickedBtns) alert('passed check'); // compare counts
  }
```

```css
.screen .button-container > div{
  padding:10px;
  width:auto;
  background-color:#eee;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="screen">
  <div class="button-container">
    <div data-clicked="false">Test button</div>
    <div data-clicked="false">Test button</div>
    <div data-clicked="false">Test button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```